# PHP: Refresh Token disappears when browser is closed.

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

So I'm using the PHP client library for google oauth2. I need to make a presistent session for the app I'm building. The refresh token appears when a user firsts logs in. However, when a user closes the browser and logs into the app again, the refresh token is no longer there and after an hour the session is gone.

I know that the access type should be set to:
           access_type = 'offline'

and the approval prompt to: 
           approval_prompt = 'auto'

My question is, how do I make the session last longer than 1 hour? Do I need to store the tokens somewhere (ie. A database, cookie, etc.). If so, how would I do that? I'm having trouble understanding how to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to save the token somewhere if you want to keep the user's authorization beyond his browser session. You can save it on the database and after he logs in in your app, you use the `$client->setAccessToken($token)` method to load your saved token.

I'm not sure if the PHP lib refreshes the token automatically, but if not, you can do something like this after setting the token:

```
if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $token_data = json_decode($token);
    $client->refreshToken($token_data->refresh_token);
}
```